# Preparing Data With CommandLineRunner & @PostConstruct

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to populate data from a text file to a relational DB and use the data from the DB to construct a data structure, Tire. The DB is a memory-based one.

As the conventional approach, I have the data population code in a CommandLineRunner method of the @SpringBootApplication class and the data retrieval code in a @PostConstruct method of a service class. That, however, doesn't work as I thought because @PostConstruct method is executed before the CommandLineRunner.

To solve the problem, I move the data retrieval code to the CommandLineRunner method as well. The approach creates a code coupling, however, because the data structure is only used inside the service class. Another approach, I can think of, is to have a lazy data initialization for the data structure. Due to the data size, near 110k entries, the first time running time of the data structure usage will be very slow.

Any better approach?

Comment: Maybe using another `CommandLineRunner` to retrieve the data and using order annotation @Order. Or Another approach would be using using the application start event provided by spring, checkout the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the application start event:

```
   // you can put this in any wired class or even in the Application class
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
         //Now you are sure Command line runner is done. 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to use Asynchronous Events in this case.